# Solving require statement not part of an import statement

Tags: typescript, require

I have this in my typescript file:

const superagent = require("superagent");

require("superagent-retry-delay")(superagent);

This compiles and I can use them fine. However, I want to make those imports instead. 
How can I do that? 
superagent currently has a @types module but superagen-retry-delay doesn't

Answer (score 2):

```
import superagent from 'superagent';
import superagentRetryDelay from 'superagent-retry-delay' ;

const whateverBReturns = superagentRetryDelay(superagent);
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the modules I used. what you suggested didn't work.

Comment: It should work though. Maybe the errors you receive would help. Also your tsconfig would help.

Comment: but superagent can only be exported through import  superagent = require('superagent') given the export in @types/superagent.

Comment: Also I should note that I am using typescript

Comment: Try to add allowSyntheticDefaultImports and esModuleInterop, both set to true, into your tsconfig compilerOptions